# Сортировка данных в таблице, данные берутся из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, из базы берется данные, по последнему столбцу (Сумма) пытаюсь сортировку сделать (сверху больше), через ORDER пытался, не выходит.

```html
<form style="margin: 0px;" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; echo "?offset=".$_REQUEST['offset'].$q_string; ?>" name="form1" >
<input type="hidden" name="offset" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['offset'];?>">
<?php
   if ($count > $records_per_page)  {
     // calculate number of pages & current page
     echo "<center>";
     $label["navigation_page"] =  str_replace ("%CUR_PAGE%", $cur_page, $label["navigation_page"]);
     $label["navigation_page"] =  str_replace ("%PAGES%", $pages, $label["navigation_page"]);
    //echo "<span > ".$label["navigation_page"]."</span> ";
    $nav = nav_pages_struct( $q_string, $count, $records_per_page );
    $LINKS = 10;
    render_nav_pages($nav, $LINKS, $q_string);
    echo "</center>";
  }
?>
<table id="ratingTable" width="100%" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="3" align="center" bgColor="#d9d9d9" border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>CompName</th>
    <th>Pixels</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
 $i=0;
 while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) && ($i<$records_per_page)) {
   $i++;
   $sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity) as Pixels FROM orders where (status='completed') AND user_id=".intval($row['ID']);
   $result2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connection'], $sql) or die (mysqli_error($GLOBALS['connection']).$sql);
   $order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders where user_id='".intval($row['ID'])."' AND status <> 'new' ";
   $result3 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connection'], $sql) or die (mysqli_error($GLOBALS['connection']));
   //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<tbody>
   <tr class="item">
   <td><?php echo $row['FirstName'] . " / " . $row['LastName'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['CompName'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo ($order_row['Pixels'] * 0.15). " $ ";?></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<?php
   }
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Что конкретно через ORDER не выходит?

Comment: Сортировка не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С таблицами и сортировкой можно работать со стороны клиента и фронта. На js много плагинов для этого. Посмотрите например [tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). Это упростит код бэкэнда.

Comment: Пробовал, не выходит

Comment: так не бывает же, показывайте как пробовали значит

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FRK0a6Ae

Comment: Была ошибка в tbody, исправил, заработал! Спасибо!